# Can I replicate GIMP's HSL composite function with Python/OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, gimp

Is it possible to combine three grayscale images into a color HSL image just like the GIMP's Compose function? I already managed to do the classic RGB composite with simple cv2.merge([R,G,B]) where R,G,B were the grayscale images opened via imread.
Is there a simple solution like that for HSL too?

Comment: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html

Answer (score 3):

If you have 3 grayscale images in Python/OpenCV and they correspond to H,S,V channels then create any 3 channel image of your desired (W,H) and put those 3 grayscale images into each channel, respectively, and then convert to BGR if desired.

```
hsv = np.zeros((W,H), dtype=np.uint8)
hsv[:,:,0] = H
hsv[:,:,1] = S
hsv[:,:,2] = V
bgr = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
```

Comment: Hue ranges from `0` to `180`, so you should normalize `H` channel to get a valid openCV HSV colorspace.

Comment: `@iGian`  Correct. I had assumed that had been done if he had a proper H grayscale image to insert.